# Update %PATH% environment variable using NSIS

Tags: windows, path, installation, environment-variables, nsis

I've read that *"Strings longer than ${NSIS_MAX_STRLEN} **(1024)** will get truncated/corrupted."*

How can I **safely** update `%PATH%` environment variable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use an alternative NSIS build from the [special builds page](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Special_Builds) like the [large strings build](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Special_Builds#Large_strings) that defines `NSIS_MAX_STRLEN=8192` and should prevent you from breaking the host path.

In practice, on a desktop machine, 1024 byte seems enough, but on a development host with many tools installed (like mine), the path might be broken after manipulation, while the 8192 bytes strings build had never perturbed my machine.

To be very sure, you can add a check on the path length before manipulation and abort the installer with a message in the case where the path would be close to the `NSIS_MAX_STRLEN` constant before trying to manipulate it.

Answer (score 7):

I prefer using windows command processor (`cmd.exe`) via the NSIS `nsExec::Exec` command, which allows you to append to the `PATH` easily like so:

```
; Check if the path entry already exists and write result to $0
nsExec::Exec 'echo %PATH% | find "c:\some\new\dir"'
Pop $0   ; gets result code

${If} $0 = 0
    nsExec::Exec 'setx PATH=%PATH%;c:\some\new\dir'
${EndIf}
```

Using this method, `CMD.EXE` expands the `PATH` variable internally, safe from any NSIS string length limits. Alternatively, change the order of `%PATH%` token pasting if you want your program to be picked up *first*, ahead of anything and everything else that might be installed on the system by the same name:

```
    nsExec::Exec 'setx PATH=c:\some\new\dir;%PATH%'
```

Note that it's important *not* to include double-quotes while building the new `PATH`.  The command processor never expects double-quotes in the PATH string and may behave in unexpected ways if you add any.  It delimits paths by semicolon (`;`) only.

Also note that this methods depends on the [large strings build](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31341378/786437) as [explained by Seki in his answer](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Special_Builds#Large_strings).

`nsExec::Exec` differs from `ExecWait` in that it runs internally, without popping up additional visible cmd prompt windows.

Comment: This seems to truncate the result for me.

Comment: I get the following error when running that manually on command line :

ERROR: Invalid syntax.

Type "SETX /?" for usage

Answer (score 5):

The real solution is to write a custom plugin or call the Windows API directly with the system plugin so you can avoid the NSIS buffer length limitation:

```
!include LogicLib.nsh
!include WinCore.nsh
!ifndef NSIS_CHAR_SIZE
!define NSIS_CHAR_SIZE 1
!endif

Function RegAppendString
System::Store S
Pop $R0 ; append
Pop $R1 ; separator
Pop $R2 ; reg value
Pop $R3 ; reg path
Pop $R4 ; reg hkey
System::Call 'ADVAPI32::RegCreateKey(i$R4,tR3,*i.r1)i.r0'
${If} $0 = 0
    System::Call 'ADVAPI32::RegQueryValueEx(ir1,tR2,i0,*i.r2,i0,*i0r3)i.r0'
    ${If} $0 <> 0
        StrCpy $2 ${REG_SZ}
        StrCpy $3 0
    ${EndIf}
    StrLen $4 $R0
    StrLen $5 $R1
    IntOp $4 $4 + $5
    IntOp $4 $4 + 1 ; For \0
    !if ${NSIS_CHAR_SIZE} > 1
        IntOp $4 $4 * ${NSIS_CHAR_SIZE}
    !endif
    IntOp $4 $4 + $3
    System::Alloc $4
    System::Call 'ADVAPI32::RegQueryValueEx(ir1,tR2,i0,i0,isr9,*ir4r4)i.r0'
    ${If} $0 = 0
    ${OrIf} $0 = ${ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND}
        System::Call 'KERNEL32::lstrlen(t)(ir9)i.r0'
        ${If} $0 <> 0
            System::Call 'KERNEL32::lstrcat(t)(ir9,tR1)'
        ${EndIf}
        System::Call 'KERNEL32::lstrcat(t)(ir9,tR0)'
        System::Call 'KERNEL32::lstrlen(t)(ir9)i.r0'
        IntOp $0 $0 + 1
        !if ${NSIS_CHAR_SIZE} > 1
            IntOp $0 $0 * ${NSIS_CHAR_SIZE}
        !endif
        System::Call 'ADVAPI32::RegSetValueEx(ir1,tR2,i0,ir2,ir9,ir0)i.r0'
    ${EndIf}
    System::Free $9
    System::Call 'ADVAPI32::RegCloseKey(ir1)'
${EndIf}
Push $0
System::Store L
FunctionEnd

Section

Push ${HKEY_CURRENT_USER}
Push "Environment"
Push "Path"
Push ";"
Push "c:\whatever"
Call RegAppendString
Pop $0
DetailPrint RegAppendString:Error=$0

SectionEnd
```

Comment: I only did minor testing on the RegAppendString function, ideally you would force zero termination, check if it already has the separator at the end and perform all of this in a loop to avoid issues with the string changing between the calls to RegQueryValueEx.

Answer (score 3):

I was frustrated looking at all the complicated plugins and char limitations with the NSIS stuff so I wrote a tiny little application called PathEd to take care of all.

[image: PathEd.exe]

It is designed to be deployed within your installer and can be called from its deploy location like this, for example:

`PathEd.exe add "C:\Program Files\RepoZ"`
or
`PathEd.exe remove "C:\Program Files\RepoZ"`

PathEd takes care of the semicolon handling, duplicate avoidance, case-insensitive checks, user account control prompts, argument quote handling, safe and defensive value removal and so on.

Feel free to use it. But then, don't forget to give it a star on GitHub.

See https://github.com/awaescher/PathEd

Comment: Used this in my own project just now.  This application works great!  It can be implemented in three lines of NSI code.  Definitely the best and easiest option.  @Waescher , you've received my star.

Answer (score 0):

I have been wrote the NSIS 3.0 example to handle cases longer than the limit and without a need to install anything. Answered the question here: [Set environment variables with NSIS in Window 7](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42909177/6951728)