# Modify Environment Variable Path for local machine with nsis

Tags: environment-variables, nsis

I'm trying to edit the Local Machine Environment Variable Path with an NSIS script. I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31340823/update-path-environment-variable-using-nsis) interesting post but I haven't been able to "install", if I may say, the alternative build of NSIS they've been talking about in the first answer.

I did try things like [this](http://forums.winamp.com/showthread.php?t=380834) post but without success.

BUT I've managed to use the script from Anders's answer on the same question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31342128/9255799)
The thing is, it only modify the Path Environment table for the **current user**, and I want to modify it for the **local machine**.

I've tried to modify the variable here :

> Push ${HKEY_CURRENT_USER}

to :

> Push ${HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE}

but it seems to be not enough because I keep getting an error 87.

So my questions are: Is it possible from Anders's script to modify Environment Variable for the Local Machine ? And if yes, how ?

Best regards, Antoine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key used by HKLM is also different but once you give it the correct key it works for me:

```
!include LogicLib.nsh
!include WinCore.nsh
!ifndef NSIS_CHAR_SIZE
!define NSIS_CHAR_SIZE 1
!endif
!ifndef HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
!error HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
!endif

Function RegAppendString
TODO: Function from https://stackoverflow.com/a/31342128/3501# goes here
FunctionEnd

RequestExecutionLevel Admin ; Request UAC elevation

Section

Push ${HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE}
Push "SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment"
Push "Path"
Push ";"
Push "c:\whatever"
Call RegAppendString
Pop $0
DetailPrint RegAppendString:Error=$0

SectionEnd
```

but things have moved on since that function was posted and there is now a plug-in specifically created for environment variable manipulation. I would recommend that you try the [EnVar plug-in](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/EnVar_plug-in).