# Inno Setup - Setting Java Environment Variable

Tags: environment-variables, inno-setup

I am using Inno Setup to make an installer for a project I am working on, and I need it to set the java environment variable, so that when they run cmd they don't get a *java not found* error, or something like that.

I have found a few other posts related to Inno Setup and the setting environment variables, but does anyone know something specific to this instance?

Comment: Doesn't the Java runtime installer already do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Assuming Java is installed in its default location program files/Java, something like this should work in your case:

```
[Registry]
; set PATH
Root: HKCU; Subkey: "Environment"; ValueType:string; ValueName:"PATH"; ValueData:"{olddata};{pf}\Java\bin"; Flags: preservestringtype
; set JAVA_HOME
Root: HKCU; Subkey: "Environment"; ValueType:string; ValueName:"JAVA_HOME"; ValueData:"{pf}\Java"; Flags: preservestringtype

[Setup]
; Tell Windows Explorer to reload the environment
ChangesEnvironment=yes
```

I'm not sure which environment variable you want to set -- PATH or JAVA_HOME -- so I've added them both.

Changing PATH shouldn't be necessary since the Java installer tends to add itself to the path; IIRC it copies java.exe and javaw.exe to one of the system directories.

Comment: Don't forget the ChangesEnvironment directive.

Comment: @Deanna thanks, I didn't know about that one! Now I can remove the requirement to restart from one of our installers.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but this was the answer I was looking for and worked perfectly.

Comment: Note that there's a missing ";" right before the "Flags" section in each line.

Comment: You can check out the installation directory from the registry and use script constants to set it (see [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29535962/1098603)).

Comment: This is going to add the var only for the current user and not for the machine. You need to use Root: HKLM; Subkey: "SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" to add a global var.

Answer (score 2):

Adding up to @Joni's answer, you can get the Java installation directory from the registry and use script constants to set your environment variable:

(EDIT: thanks to @TLama for code correction!)

```
[Registry]
Root: HKCU; Subkey: "Environment"; ValueType:string; ValueName:"JAVA_HOME"; ValueData:"{code:GetJava32Path|6}"; Flags: preservestringtype

[Code]
const
  RegKeyJRE = 'SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment\';

function GetJava32Path(MinVersion: string): string;
var
  I: Integer;
  Path: string;
  Versions: TArrayOfString;
begin
  Result := '';
  if RegGetSubkeyNames(HKLM, RegKeyJRE, Versions) then
    for I := 0 to GetArrayLength(Versions)-1 do
      if (Versions[I][2] = '.') and (Versions[I][3] >= MinVersion) and
        RegQueryStringValue(HKLM32, RegKeyJRE + Versions[I], 'JavaHome', Path) then
      begin
        Result := Path;
        Exit;
      end;
end;
```

(N.B. I'm far from being a Pascal-script expert, the code could be a lot better, though now it was corrected by @TLama :))

Comment: Your code is definitely correct (could have been [`shortened`](http://pastebin.com/bttNaCEG) by removing those extra `begin..end` blocks, there might be a constant for the JRE registry key path (DRY sort of) and there could be removed one `if` by using `and` operator, and return from the function could have been `exit` rather than `break` - all minor, or cosmetic things).

Comment: @TLama thanks a lot, I have both pasted your code and learnt a few things :)