# How to set a global environment variable from Inno Setup installer?

Tags: environment-variables, installation, inno-setup

How do I set a global environment variable in Inno Setup?

<sup>Background: I am using the Inno install utility and need to set a global environment variable before I do the actual install.</sup>

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21708140/environment-variable-not-recognized-not-available-for-run-programs-in-inno-s and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10687188/inno-setup-setting-java-environment-variable

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this:

```
[Registry]
Root: HKCU; Subkey: "Environment"; ValueType:string; ValueName: "VARIABLE_NAME"; \
    ValueData: "new_value"; Flags: preservestringtype
```

You might need to add this:

```
[Setup]
; Tell Windows Explorer to reload the environment
ChangesEnvironment=yes
```

---

Alternatively try:

```pascal
[Run]
Filename: "{app}\MyProg.exe"; BeforeInstall: SetEnvPath

[Code]
#ifdef UNICODE
  #define AW "W"
#else
  #define AW "A"
#endif

function SetEnvironmentVariable(lpName: string; lpValue: string): BOOL;
  external 'SetEnvironmentVariable{#AW}@kernel32.dll stdcall';

procedure SetEnvPath;
begin
  if not SetEnvironmentVariable('VARIABLE_NAME', 'new_value') then
    MsgBox(SysErrorMessage(DLLGetLastError), mbError, MB_OK);
end;
```

Reference: [Inno Setup Frequently Asked Questions - Setting Environment Variables](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isfaq.php#env)

If the variable change is not propagated (see [Environment variable not recognized [not available] for [Run] programs in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21708140/environment-variable-not-recognized-not-available-for-run-programs-in-inno-s))

```pascal
[Run]
...; AfterInstall: RefreshEnvironment

[Code]
const
  SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG = 2;
  WM_WININICHANGE = $001A;
  WM_SETTINGCHANGE = WM_WININICHANGE;

type
  WPARAM = UINT_PTR;
  LPARAM = INT_PTR;
  LRESULT = INT_PTR;

function SendTextMessageTimeout(hWnd: HWND; Msg: UINT;
  wParam: WPARAM; lParam: PAnsiChar; fuFlags: UINT;
  uTimeout: UINT; out lpdwResult: DWORD): LRESULT;
  external 'SendMessageTimeoutA@user32.dll stdcall';  

procedure RefreshEnvironment;
var
  S: AnsiString;
  MsgResult: DWORD;
begin
  S := 'Environment';
  SendTextMessageTimeout(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SETTINGCHANGE, 0,
    PAnsiChar(S), SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG, 5000, MsgResult);
end;
```

---

More details:

[Inno Setup: Setting a System Environment Variable](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/w-p/win32/tutorials/article.php/c10849/Setting-a-System-Environment-Variable.htm)

> Under more modern (in other words, proper) operating systems, such as
>   Windows 2000, XP, and Windows 2003 Server, environment variables are
>   stored in the Registry under the following key:
>
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\
>                      Environment
>
> Variables are added by creating a new value under this key or by
>   modifying a value if it already exists. To delete a variable, you
>   simply delete its Registry value, unless you are removing part of an
>   expanded value, such as PATH, in which case you only remove the part
>   you want.
>
> At this point, Windows will not be aware of your changes unless you
>   log off or reboot. To get around this, SetEnv will broadcast a
>   **WM_SETTINGCHANGE** to all of the windows in the system. This allows
>   other running applications—for example, Explorer.exe—to be notified of
>   your change. If you run SetEnv from a command prompt, this will not
>   update the environment variable for the current DOS window. This is
>   mainly due to the fact that a process (SetEnv) cannot change the
>   environment of its parent (The Command Prompt). However, any new
>   DOS/Command Prompts that you open will show the new variable/value.

Comment: Then do this change from code in the `PrepareToInstall` event. For what you need to make this change ? I'm asking because processes inherit environment variable blocks, so if you'd e.g. set some environment variable by the `SetEnvironmentVariable` function, process executed from Inno Setup would see that change. However, such change would not be persistent. On the other hand you can change the variables persistently in registry (and optionally call my `RefreshEnvironment` procedure which will notify running apps about the environment change).

Comment: Here is the entire sordid story:  Some of the inno panels get information from the user.  Based on that info I may need to set an environment variable.  Then I try to start a process that will not run unless the environment variable is set.  All of this before the install.  Everything appears to be working except setting the var.  (If I set the var by hand before running the install, everything works fine.)

Comment: More background:  We are doing our own licensing scheme, and what I am trying to do is make sure they have set up their license correctly so that the installation can help them out if they are having problems.

Comment: I have also tried RegWriteDWordValue(HKEY_CURRENT_USER,'name','value',1); followed by the RefreshEnvironment call.

Comment: Oh, good point.  Then I guess my question has been answered above.

Comment: Well, comments seems to disappear from here. Never mind. To summarize this answer, the `[Registry]` entry shown here sets environment variable for the current user, the `ChangesEnvironment` directive set to `yes` notifies running apps about environment changes. However, all that is done after the installation (which doesn't meet the OP's requirement). The following `SetEnvPath` procedure sets the variable only for the setup process; this change is not persistent. And finally, the `RefreshEnvironment` procedure notifies about changes immediately, but calling it makes sense if you were...

Comment: ...making persistent changes in registry. In other words, further readers of this post will having a hard time to understand what each part of this post does since it sounds like *try this, if that won't work, try that* etc.

Comment: I had the same problem (my new environment variable was not propagated). For me helps starting of explorer.exe with parameter "myapp.exe". Filename: explorer.exe; Parameters: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Flags: postinstall nowait skipifsilent

Comment: HKCU is current user, but topic starter mentioned "global" ?

Answer (score 5):

The solutions in @Adrian's answer (actually copied from [@TLama's answer to similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21708140/850848#21709882)) are correct for many situations.

But it won't work for `[Run]` tasks with [`runasoriginaluser` flag](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=runsection&anchor=runasoriginaluser) (what is implied by [`postinstall` flag](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=runsection&anchor=postinstall)). I.e. the variable won't be propagated to an application run with common *"Run My Program"* check box on the "Finished" page.

The reason is that the tasks with `runasoriginaluser` are executed by a un-elevated hidden parent process of the Inno Setup installer. The `SetEnvironmentVariable` will change environment for the installer, but not for its parent process. Unfortunately, the parent process of the installer cannot be controlled (imo).

As a workaround, to set the variable for the `runasoriginaluser` tasks, you have to inject an intermediate process between the installer parent process and the task, and have the intermediate process set the variable.

Such an intermediate process can easily be the `cmd.exe` with its [`set` command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/set_1):

```
[Run]
Filename: "{cmd}"; Parameters: "/C set MYVAR=MyValue & ""{app}\MyProg.exe"""; \
    Description: "Run My Program"; Flags: postinstall runhidden
```

The [`runhidden` flag](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=runsection&anchor=runhidden) hides the `cmd.exe` console window, not the application (assuming it's a GUI application). If it's a console application, use [`start`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/start) to start it in its own (visible) console window.

Answer (score 4):

What would be wrong with running two setup.exe with the first one doing the setting of the environment variables, and the second doing the things needed for the true setup. The first one would be run with setup.exe /VERYSILENT

I am doing to add an system wide environment variable:

```
[Setup]

; Tell Windows Explorer to reload the environment
ChangesEnvironment=True

[Registry]
Root: "HKLM"; Subkey: "SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment"; ValueType: string; ValueName: "EGPL_GeoLibrarian_Drive"; ValueData: "L"; Flags: createvalueifdoesntexist preservestringtype
```

Comment: What would be wrong on having two installer binaries from which one will only set an environment variable ? Ask yourself ;-) P.S. `ChangesEnvironment` does not tell anything to Windows Explorer. It broadcasts the `WM_SETTINGCHANGE` message to all top-level windows (with `lParam == "Environment"`).

Comment: hey I need your help to solve problem about environment variable in Inno setup v6.2 https://stackoverflow.com/q/77014531/14344959