# Adding to installer a form to choose a path where JDK is installed then changing environment variable

Tags: inno-setup

Update:

I have succeeded in making my installer work properly. ( added the release notes, license agreement section, choosing the location where the program is to be installed, having it generate me an destop shortcup etc.) what i want to add it, that during the instalation, I want the user to choose the path to where he has installed his JDK. I want to take this path, create a system environment variable with the name JAVA_HOME and have it's value be this chosen path. How do i do this? It is kind off diifficult to show my code because i am on my phone. But if i have to i will make an effort to do so.

Comment: Edited, take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on

- [How to set a global environment variable from Inno Setup installer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25289056/850848)
- Inno Setup FAQ [Setting Environment Variables](https://jrsoftware.org/isfaq.php#env)

```pascal
[Setup]
ChangesEnvironment=yes

[Registry]
Root: HKLM; Subkey: "SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment"; \
    ValueType: string; ValueName: "JAVA_HOME"; ValueData:"{code:GetJavaHome}"; \
    Flags: preservestringtype

[Code]

var
  JavaHomePage: TInputDirWizardPage;

procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  JavaHomePage :=
    CreateInputDirPage(
      wpSelectDir, 'Java Path', 'Where do you have Java installed to?', '', False, '');
  JavaHomePage.Add('');
end;

function GetJavaHome(Param: string): string;
begin
  Result := JavaHomePage.Values[0];
end;
```

If you want to offer some meaningful default, see also an [answer by @Matthieu to Inno Setup - Setting Java Environment Variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10687188/850848#29535962).

Comment: There's no JAVA_HOME2 in my answer (it was for a second, before I fixed it, but that's long ago).

Comment: Did my answer help you?