# How to avoid double-path on PATH environment variable? Using Inno-Setup

Tags: windows, inno-setup

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I modify the PATH environment variable when running an Inno Setup Installer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304463/how-do-i-modify-the-path-environment-variable-when-running-an-inno-setup-install)

Currently I use this line in order to add another value to PATH variable during the install:

```
[Registry]
Root: HKLM; Subkey: "SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment"; ValueType: expandsz; ValueName: "Path"; ValueData: "{olddata};{app}"; Check: NeedsAddPath('{app}');
```

My questions are:

1) How to avoid adding that variable if already exists? If a user re-install the software, so the {app} path is concatenated again and again
I checked and if I use that way with 'C:\foo'

```
 [Registry]
    Root: HKLM; Subkey: "SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment"; ValueType: expandsz; ValueName: "Path"; ValueData: "{olddata};{app}"; Check: NeedsAddPath('C:\foo');
```

It works as expected. So how to use a variable instead of a constant string?

2) How to safely remove the {app} value during uninstall?

THANK YOU

Comment: To your first question, try to check the [`deletevalue`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_registrysection.htm) flag. That flag ensures the value is deleted before a new one is written. To your second question, do you want to remove from the value data `{olddata};{app}` only the `{app}` part and keep `{olddata}` ?

Comment: @TLama, yes I do want to keep {olddata}. Thank you

Comment: I've just edited the question. The problem occurs when I try to use a variable with Check: NeedsAddPath

Can you advice please?

Comment: Can you provide the code for `NeedsAddPath` as you say that is incorrectly returning true? Maybe you need an `ExpandConstant()` on `{app}`.

Comment: Thank you Deanna! I found this function and now it works fine.

Comment: Well it works good on Windwos 2008 (64bit) but now I see that it doesn't work on Windows 7 (64 bit). Yet it concatenating existing path. What could it be?