# Registry aren't fully deleting when uninstalling

Tags: registry, inno-setup

Inno Setup isn't deleting the full registry key. Here is what I have done:

```
[Registry]
Root: HKLM; SubKey: SOFTWARE\EA Games\Need for Speed Most Wanted-2012; ValueType: string; ValueName: GDFBinary; ValueData: {app}\GDFBinary_en_US.dll; Flags: uninsdeletekey
Root: HKLM; SubKey: SOFTWARE\EA Games\Need for Speed Most Wanted-2012; ValueType: string; ValueName: DisplayName; ValueData: Need for Speed Most Wanted-2012; Flags: uninsdeletekey
Root: HKLM; SubKey: SOFTWARE\EA Games\Need for Speed Most Wanted-2012; ValueType: string; ValueName: Locale; ValueData: en_US; Flags: uninsdeletekey
Root: HKLM; SubKey: SOFTWARE\EA Games\Need for Speed Most Wanted-2012; ValueType: string; ValueName: Install Dir; ValueData: {app}; Flags: uninsdeletekey
```

These part isn't deleting when uninstalling: `\EA Games\Need for Speed Most Wanted-2012` folder in registry

```
Root: HKLM; SubKey: SOFTWARE\EA Games\Need for Speed Most Wanted-2012
```

(`Need for Speed Most Wanted-2012` game is only for hint).

Anybody please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code, as it is, automatically deletes the `HKLM\SOFTWARE\EA Games\Need for Speed Most Wanted-2012`. The `HKLM\SOFTWARE\EA Games` is not deleted.

If you want to delete even the `HKLM\SOFTWARE\EA Games`, you have to add an explicit code for it:

```
Root: HKLM; SubKey: SOFTWARE\EA Games; Flags: uninsdeletekeyifempty
```

(This should be placed *before* your other entries).

The entry will delete only empty key `SOFTWARE\EA Games`. If other subkeys are created (not by the installer), the key won't be deleted. If you want to delete the `EA Games` key unconditionally, replace `uninsdeletekeyifempty` with `uninsdeletekey`.

Comment: I know it is correct, I just want to delete that `HKLM\SOFTWARE\EA Games` Part automatically.Is it possible with inno setup?

Comment: You refer to `Need for Speed Most Wanted-2012` is your question. Please correct it. As it is now, it's pretty unclear what the problem is.

Comment: I just tried and it worked so i have to just put the apppublisher before all the keys. I have one more question is this Processes will delete all the subfolder inside it.I need them deleted too.Thanks i will make the question as answered .

Comment: Thanks thats what i wanted.@ Martin Prikryl 1 .

Comment: Thanks for solving my problem.@ Martin Prikryl 1 .Now i am fully satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

Some time after installing software if we apply any  offline patch in such case previous un-installer got replaced by new. so in such case we have to remove these registry key manually as follows:

```pascal
usDone: 
   begin
       if RegKeyExists(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{078ABE12-583D-43e6-96D6-5D092883DC82}_is1') then
       begin
         RegDeleteKeyIncludingSubkeys(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{078ABE12-583D-43e6-96D6-5D092883DC82}_is1');
      end;
```

Comment: I think Martin Prikryl got a better answer.@lalit kishor kumawat