# i made an app using python i need to add it to command line when it's installed

Tags: python-3.x, command-line-interface

I'm using inno setup tool for installing my app in windows,is there any why to add my app to command line ,so user can access my app through cli

Comment: You need to add the directory where the `.exe` is located to `PATH`.

Comment: I need to add my app when it's installed first time by inno setup,how can i do that using inno setup only

Comment: This is documented in a lot of places online, for example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304463/how-do-i-modify-the-path-environment-variable-when-running-an-inno-setup-install