# InnoSetup python subprocess Popen ffmpeg

Tags: python, ffmpeg, inno-setup

In my code i have this line:

```py
self.p1 = Popen([self.ffmpeg_path,'-y','-loglevel','quiet','-i',self.retransmition_url,'epalxeis-radio.mp3'],stdin=PIPE,stdout=PIPE,stderr=PIPE, bufsize=1)
```

which read an web radio stream and saves it locally with filename "epalxeis-radio.mp3"

Using python to launch the script - works!
Using pyinstaller to launch the exe - works!
Using InnoSetup to launch the exe after installation - not working :(.

The problem is that there is no epalxeis-radio.mp3 created when i try the third case (innosetup).

The ffmpeg_path is: `self.ffmpeg_path = os.path.abspath("extra/ffmpeg.exe")`
and there is the extra folder in the same directory which is the innosetup exe.

From Windows task manager there is no ffmpeg.exe shown in the tasks list.

What wrong?

**Edit:** I used a smaller script to test the error:

```py
from subprocess import Popen, DEVNULL, STDOUT, PIPE
import os
import time
ffmpeg_path = os.path.abspath("extra/ffmpeg.exe")
retransmition_url = "http://shaincast.caster.fm:40636/listen.mp3?authn76260dc1cdf44a9132c0b63f85d9c67a"
with Popen([ffmpeg_path,'-y','-loglevel','quiet','-i',retransmition_url,'epalxeis-radio.mp3'],stdin=PIPE,stdout=PIPE,stderr=PIPE) as p1:
    time.sleep(1)
```

in pyinstaller exe runs, but in innosetup exe stop immediately.

Comment: Add a few `print`s, especially a `print(self.ffmpeg_path)` as the full path may not be what you expect.

Comment: ffmpeg_path = `C:\Program Files (x86)\Epalxeis Radio Player\extra\ffmpeg.exe` after print.

Comment: I delete `, buffsize=1` same problem.

Comment: I will make a single script to be sure that this is the problem.

Comment: See [Application does not work when installed with Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44333839/850848).

Comment: Perfect, if i run as administrator works.
That's because the ffmpeg_process is trying to write in C:/Program Files (x86)/ folder!!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that ffmpeg will want write permission in a folder that application doesn't have write permission.

So to solve this problem, i change self.ffmpeg_path to C:/extra/(ff****.exe)
And then append this path to system enviroment variables by adding a registry entry in innosetup file.

Code:

```
[Registry]
Root: HKCU; Subkey: "Environment"; \
    ValueType: expandsz; ValueName: "Path"; ValueData: "{olddata};C:\extra"
```

To avoid repeated entries after uninstall - reinstall, use this code [as suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304463/how-do-i-modify-the-path-environment-variable-when-running-an-inno-setup-install#answers):

```
[Registry]
Root: HKCU; Subkey: "Environment"; \
    ValueType: expandsz; ValueName: "Path"; ValueData: "{olddata};C:\extra"; \
    Check: NeedsAddPath('C:\extra')


[Code]

function NeedsAddPath(Param: string): boolean;
var
  OrigPath: string;
begin
  if not RegQueryStringValue(HKEY_CURRENT_USER,
    'Environment',
    'Path', OrigPath)
  then begin
    Result := True;
    exit;
  end;
  { look for the path with leading and trailing semicolon }
  { Pos() returns 0 if not found }
  Result := Pos(';' + Param + ';', ';' + OrigPath + ';') = 0;
end;
```